# Why doesn't setting the default value of a jQuery UI datepicker to an anonymous function work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, anonymous-function

I'm really curious as to why this code to set the defaultDate to a date 25 years ago from today works properly...

```
$('div.recipient_modal input[name="birth_date"]:first').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    defaultDate: get_recipient_default_birth_date(),
    yearRange: 'c-125:' + new Date().getFullYear()
});

function get_recipient_default_birth_date()
{
    var d = new Date();
    var y = d.getFullYear() - 25;
    d.setFullYear(y);
    return $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', d);
}
```

But when I try to set the default date to 25 years ago from today using an anonymous function rather than calling a named function that has the same code like below...

```
    $('div.recipient_modal input[name="birth_date"]:first').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    defaultDate: function() {
        var d = new Date();
        var y = d.getFullYear() - 25;
        d.setFullYear(y);
        return $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', d);
    },
    yearRange: 'c-125:' + new Date().getFullYear(),
});
```

I get the following error in the console...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
        var d = new Date();
        var y = d.getFullYear() - 25;
        d.setFullYear(y);
        return $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', d);
    } has no method 'getTime'
```

Can anyone explain the difference in these two assignments and why the anonymous function doesn't work but the named function does?

Thank You.

Comment: you forgot to execute the function expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already described why it isn't working: You're setting the *anonymous function* as the value.

Not the return value from the anonymous function.

In your first, working, example, you are calling the function which returns the value for the default. In your second example, you are simply defining an anonymous function and assigning it directly as the value - without calling it.

If you want to use an anonymous function like that, you will need to actually call it, like so:

```
defaultValue: (function() { /* stuff */; return something; })()
```

Comment: lol... yeah I guess I did describe why it isn't working in my question.  I have seen that syntax before but didn't realize that made the function get called.  I actually thought that with the way I had it written that my function would get called.  Thanks for the explanation on that syntax Jani!

Comment: @AnthonyJack An anonymous function which "calls itself" is typically called an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), see here for a more in-depth explanation http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: Thanks for the link and explanation.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that in your first example, you're actually *calling* the function, so `datepicker` is getting the *date value* returned by the function, not the function itself:

```
get_recipient_default_birth_date()
```

In the second, you're passing a function object.  Functions are not supported for that option.

Comment: Thanks Jacob.  I didn't realize that the function itself was an object.  I thought that the function I assigned would get executed and therefore the value would be the date value.